# Hyperledger Fabric client and metrics for nodejs application

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js, hyperledger-fabric-orderer, hyperldger-fabric-peer

I trying to implement the metrics in nodejs application using fabric-network, I'm new to fabric-sdk-node and not able to figure out how to access functionalities (eg : system chaincode methods and other method like Fabric Version) hosted by peers and orderer services and how to use them in nodejs application.

I have tried and access user-chaicode methods using fabric-network but I'm not able figure out how to get core functionalities of peers and orderer ('peer version' or total number of transaction per channel) in nodejs application

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.